# 2 for loops nested and selected inside one based on outer

Tags: php, arrays

I have these arrays:

```
$payments = array(1=>'Cash',2=>Cheque,3=>credit,4=>other);
$selected = array(2,1);

foreach($payments as $key=>$value) {
   foreach($selected as $id) {
      if ($key == $id) {
         echo $id . "is selected" . '<br>';
      }
      else{
          echo $id . " is not selected" . '<br>';
      }
   }
}

 what expected:
 1 is selected
 2 is not selected
 3 is not selected
 4 is selected

 but i got:
 1 is not selected
 1 is selected
 2 is selected
 2 is not selected
 3 is not selected
 3 is not selected
 4 is not selected
 4 is not selected
```

what's the wrong in my loops?

Comment: lol, 4 nearly identical answers within a minute.

Comment: Why do you expect these results by the way? It's not consistent with your $selected array, which would implies that only 2 and 1 are selected.

Comment: I don't think that OP got the expected answer

Comment: Thanks guys all answers below are correct. forgot in_array :)

Comment: Then please update the question with the expected answer and accept one of those answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if an element is selected:

```
$payments = array(1=>'Cash',2=>'Cheque',3=>'credit',4=>'other');
$selected = array(2,1);

foreach($payments as $key=>$value) {
   if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
      echo $value . "is selected" . '<br>';
   } else {
      echo $value . " is not selected" . '<br>';
   }
}
```

By the way, you need quotes around the payment method names.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need inner loop:

```
$payments = array(1=>'Cash',2=>Cheque,3=>credit,4=>other);
$selected = array(2,1);

foreach($payments as $key=>$value) {
  if (in_array($key, $selected)( {
     echo $key . "is selected" . '<br>';
  } else {
      echo $key . " is not selected" . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead, so you can omit your inner loop:

```
foreach($payments as $key=>$value) {  
  if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
     echo $id . "is selected" . '<br>';
  }else{
      echo $id . " is not selected" . '<br>';
  }
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/322103)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** an alternative solution. Not better (maybe), but different :)

```
$payments = array(1=>'Cash', 2=>'Cheque', 3=>'Credit', 4=>'Other');
$selected = array('Cash','Cheque');

foreach($selected as $chosen){  
    $selected_values = array_search($chosen, $payments);
    echo "Number ". $selected_values." (".$chosen.") is selected.<br>";
}
```

[You can see the output here](https://eval.in/322118)

---

*Old* solution (as everyone else...)

```
    $payments = array(1=>'Cash', 2=>'Cheque',3=>'Credit',4=>'Other');

    $selected = array(2,1);

    foreach($payments as $key=>$value) {  
      if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
         echo $key. " is selected" . '<br>';
      }else{
          echo $key. " is not selected" . '<br>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: To OP: please let me know if this is what you want or if I can help you in any other way with the array. Have a nice day.